# the roots of the equation $ax^2 +bx+c=0$ are $\alpha$ and $\beta$ find an equation with roots $\alpha + \beta$ and $\alpha \beta$.

Tags: polynomials

> The roots of the equation $ax^2 +bx+c=0$ where $a,b,c \in\Bbb Z^+$ are $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Find a quadratic with integer coefficients whose roots are $\alpha + \beta$ and $\alpha \beta$.

So my workings are below but from graphing a few curves with my equation, it hasn't seemed to work. Any help would be great.

$$\alpha + \beta = \frac {-b} {a} $$
$$\alpha \beta = \frac c a$$

So the new equation will need to have roots $\frac {-b} {a} $ and $\frac c a$. so the equation can be written in the form $(x-p)(x-q)=0$ meaning the new equation is 
$$(x+\frac {b} {a})(x-\frac c a) = x^2 +(\frac b a - \frac c a )x - \frac {bc}{a^2}=0$$
$$a^2x+a(b-c)x-bc=0$$
This final answer doesn't seem to yield me the correct result when graphing, any help would be great.

Comment: Why do you think that the result is wrong?

Comment: When graphing it, it didn't seem to work. Is my logic correct?

Comment: Of course I may be overlooking something, but I cannot see an obvious error. – Can you provide a concrete example where your result is wrong?

Comment: so if you take $x^2 +3x-10$ which has roots -5 and 2. the equation I've got gives $x^2+13x-30$ which isn't right as it has roots 2 and -15. neither of which are result of summation or multiplication.

Comment: Your method gives $x^2+13x+30$, having the roots $-3$ and $-10$.

Comment: Ok, maybe I've just made a sign error in my workings somewhere then

Comment: @H.Linkhorn Yeah, it's $-bc/a^2$, and since $c$ is negative, it's $+30$.

Answer (score 1):

It is a high-school theorem that, $s$ and $p$ being given, if the sum of two numbers (not necessarily distinct) is $s$ and their product is $p$, these numbers are the roots of the quadratic equation:
$$x^2-sx+p=0.$$
So your answer is perfectly correct.

Comment: I know this, and have used it within my workings but I want an equation which has roots $\alpha + \beta$ and $\alpha \beta$ given the original has roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Comment: You use this theorem, after you've calculated the sum and the product with Vieta's relations.